# lfetch data from table to text box

Tags: html, jquery, datatables, fetch

I am creating a table through jQuery and in this table I concatenate 3 columns in 1 column:

so how i concatenate multiple columns in 1 column 
Before concatenate:

```
if (re.length > 0) {
    $("#services_schdulue").append
     $('#services_schdulue thead').append("<tr><th>Service ID</th><th>Service Type</th><th>frequency</th><th>Freq_Duration</th><th>Freq_Mileage</th></tr>");

    for (var i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
        if (re[i] !== null) {
            $('#services_schdulue tbody').append('<tr><td>' + re[i][0] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][1] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][2] + 
                '</td><td>' + re[i][3] 
                '</td><td>' + re[i][4] +
                '</td></tr>');                                                               
        }
    }
}
```

After concatenate:

```
if (re.length > 0) {
    $("#services_schdulue").append
    $('#services_schdulue thead').append("<tr><th>Service ID</th><th>Service Type</th><th>S freq</th></tr>");

    for (var i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
        if (re[i] !== null) {
            $('#services_schdulue tbody').append('<tr><td>' + re[i][0] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][1] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][2] + '' + re[i][3] + '' + re[i][4] +
                '</td></tr>');       
        }
    }
}

var myTable = $('#services_schdulue').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{ 
        "visible": false, 
        "targets": [3,4,5] 
    }]               
});
```

Comment: why don't you take data from the `re` ?

Comment: how i modify this line var rowDate = myTable.row(this).data();
        $("#txt_repeat").val(rowDate[2]);  @chiragpatel

Comment: Just, really, get rid of concatenating your data and use DataTables to hide the columns you don't want to display. That simply is the best way and then you don't need to worry about splitting some text into what you want to display. I'm sorry to keep banging on about this but I'm not alone in wanting a JSFiddle to work against... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution , i think this will help you.

```
$('#services_schdulue').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var row = $(this)[0];
        console.log(re[row._DT_RowIndex]);
});
```

In console you find the entire data of the row , which row you click.

As per your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtnwgz09/18/), below solution is help to you. **Don't fogot to declare variable `re` outside of the `document.ready`**

```
    $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        $("#myModal").modal("show");
            var row = $(this);
            var row_index = row[0]._DT_RowIndex;
            var data = re[row_index];

            $("#txt_status").val(data.Status);
            debugger;
            //var repeat = myTable.row.find('td')[2].firstChild.data;
            $("#txt_speed").val(data.Speed);
        });
```

Comment: i dont want to show data in console .. want to show data in text box @chirag patel

Comment: @greenuser , can you make one jsfiddle? so i can easily change your code

Comment: ok .. this is https://jsfiddle.net/wtnwgz09/18/... but  i want to merge status and speed column and give header " infor"

 and data in td column will be like this "def 1000" so after hiding status and speed columns .. 
only 

NO    infor  refrence 
column will be visible.. 
so after this when i click on row then pop up is appear with textbox Status and Speed 
so how i fetch hidden columns data in these text box

Comment: @greenuser , here you can check the solution [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11q74zge/2/)